# Is a bit of disc brake rubbing normal?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I bought a new roadbike with shimano ultegra hydraulic disc brakes. After I rode a couple thousands km, my disc brake pads started to rub the rotor, but just a little bit (it barely touches it, I can only hear it when I'm standing next to my bike, heave the wheel and roll it by hand).

I usually re-align the brake caliper, so it doesn't rub anymore, but the next day before ride I can hear it again (again, just a little bit)... Is this normal? I tighten it by 7Nm what should be sufficient, so I don't think that the caliper moves. I checked the brake pads, they are not worn out yet, but I also replaced them. The issue still remains.

thanks,
Mat

Comment: Are you saying that it is a constant rub as the wheel turns? Or does it just rub on one section or spot on the disc?

Comment: just on 1-2 little spots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should rotors have no rub at all?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/21510/33268)

Comment: Voted to reopen, there is a subtle difference between the questions.
'Should' a disc rotor rub? No.  Is it 'normal' for a disc rotor to rub? Yes

Comment: Also, why is the bot allowed to bypass the vote close process?

Comment: If it's only in 1 or 2 spots, the disc is slightly warped and I would say no, it's not normal. However, it is common. It's not something I would just let go and try to ignore. I would fix it. Park (and others) make a nice tool meant for straightening warped rotors. Or just replace them, but straightening isn't all that hard.

Comment: @Geo242 And why does it bend?  If that's the case, even if straightening a solution, I would be interested what caused it. Am I doing something wrong? (Do I swing the bike too much while I'm out of the saddle or what?)

Comment: There are several reasons the rotor can get warped... impact, heat, etc. It's not something that you should have to deal with a lot. If they go out of true a lot, they may be at the end of their life. Park tool has a nice article and video on the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, 100% normal unfortunately.

I'm on to my 6th disc brake bike and all 6 have had this issue at some time or another.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this should be the accepted answer. Normal and common are not the same thing. It is common but not normal imo.

Comment: Do you re-align your brake calipers before each ride, or you just ignore it?

Comment: @Mat just ignore it.  its nearly always caused by warped rotors so re-centering the calipers doesn't help